# Numpad characters don't work in keybindings mappings (but work in general)

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout, map-operator

For my terminal Vim 8.0, I have downloaded this plugin that makes changing font size on the fly easy:
https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-fontsize

Following the instructions, here is how I decided to define my mappings for changing fonts:

```
nmap <silent> <C>+ <Plug>FontsizeInc
nmap <silent> <C-kPlus> <Plug>FontsizeDec
nmap <silent> <C>- <Plug>FontsizeDec
nmap <silent> <C-kMinus> <Plug>FontsizeDec
nmap <silent> <C>0 <Plug>FontsizeDefault
```

However, to my surprise, the functionalities are only working for the `+` and `-` characters that are *not* in the NumPad are of my keyboard. When I hit the combinations using `+` or `-` form the NumPad, nothing happens. And otherwise, my Vim recognizes the NumPad just normally.

How could I perhaps solve this issue?

Comment: Those mappings dont look quite right to my eye

Comment: Also the title of your question has nothing to do with it’s body?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ooops, my bad, I mistakenly copied and pasted the title from wrong place. Fixed it now. About the mappings, what does not look right? It works perfectly for `<C>+`, `<C>-` and `<C>0`, just not `<C-kPlus>` and `<C-kMinus>`

Comment: The typical syntax is `map <LHS> <RHS>`, but in your question i see 3 “sides” after the map commands

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Changed that, no effect

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, you are working in a terminal. Vim can't change the font size in a terminal. What you see, when pressing <kbd>Ctrl-+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl--</kbd> is a functionality  of the terminal.

Try it without starting vim.

The plugin you downloaded just changes the `guifont`.

For this I have the following in my gvimrc:

```
command! -bar -nargs=0 BiggerFont  :let &guifont = substitute(&guifont,'\d\+$','\=submatch(0)+1','')
command! -bar -nargs=0 SmallerFont :let &guifont = substitute(&guifont,'\d\+$','\=submatch(0)-1','')
nnoremap <M-->        :SmallerFont<CR>
nnoremap <M-+>        :BiggerFont<CR>
```

Stolen from [tpope](https://github.com/tpope/tpope/blob/master/.vimrc).

BTW: The {lhs} of the mappings `<C>+`, `<C>-` and `<C>0` all map a sequence of 4 characters.

BTW-2: I'm not sure that <kbd>Ctrl-+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl--</kbd> is mappable at all. If I go into insert mode in gVim and enter <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl-+</kbd> I just get a single `+`. If I use <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> I get `^L`.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the mappings, getting rid of that part. Still, the same thing: it does work with `<C>+` and `<C>-`, so it can change the fonts - I don't think it is only the terminal, because if I comment those lines out the re-sizing of the font stops working. It just does not work with the numpad keys

Comment: I'm pretty sure your terminal does that, not Vim. My GNOME-Terminal has this. It changes the font size with `<C-+>` and `<C-->` even without Vim.

Comment: You are using Vim in a terminal, not gVim? Which OS?, Which terminal emulator?